# Converting a number to text exception

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I need to convert a julian date into a date field in my Power BI model, but it's giving me an error.

By 'julian date', I mean a 6 digit number where the first three digits is the number of years after 1900, and the last three digits is the day of the year. EX. 113001 is Jan 1, 2013 (113 + 1900 = 2013, and 001 = first day of the year).

To get the year, I did this:

```
Value.FromText(Text.Range(Text.From([Load Date]), 0, 3)) + 1900
```

Which works great. Then, I needed to change that into a string so I can convert it to a date using Date.FromText, so:

```
Text.From(Value.FromText(Text.Range(Text.From([Load Date]), 0, 3)) + 1900)
```

And it doesn't work. I'm getting an error saying:

```
Unexpected error: Microsft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.Library+_Value+FromTextFunctionValue
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: It works for me. Are you adding this as a column, or are you transforming the current column? Also, do you plan on handling dates before 2000? If so, your method will generate the wrong year. Something like this should work: `Text.From(Value.FromText(Number.RoundDown([Load Date] / 1000) + 1900))`

Comment: This is going to be a new column. The code you posted worked for me. I just noticed that some of the date fields are just '0', but I don't think that would cause the Text.From in the second piece of code to fail, right?

Comment: `Text.From(0)` should return the text value "0". If you are getting an error popup you may be able to Send a Frown, which should include some useful information like the stack trace where the failure occurred.

Answer (score 0):

```
#date(1900 + Number.From(Text.Start([Load Date],3)),1,1) + #duration(Number.From(Text.End([Load Date],3))-1,0,0,0)
```

This is real date.

Regards